# Why is MSDTC behaving inconsistently while unit-testing with mstest?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, mstest, msdtc

I experience a strange issue while testing my Nhibernate repositories.

I have 10 unit-tests like the ones below. Everytime a run them in a batch the first fails and the rest succeeds. If a run them one by one they all fail. If a restart MSDTC before my testrun it sometimes behaves like before and sometimes all tests succeeds. I can´t find a pattern why it behaves like that.

I want the transaction to rollback so that a start with a clean DB for every test, therefore the transaction disposal.

The test/tests are failing due to this error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: MSDTC on server 'MYCOMPUTERNAME\SQLEXPRESS' is unavailable.

My tests looks like this:

```
[TestInitialize]
public void MyTestInitialize()
{
    _transactionScope = new TransactionScope();
}

[TestCleanup]
public void MyTestCleanup()
{
    if (_transactionScope != null)
    {                
        _transactionScope.Dispose();
        _transactionScope = null;
    }
}             

[TestMethod]
[TestCategory("RepositoryTests")]
public void RepositoryCanSaveAProduct()
{
    var platform = ProductObjectMother.CreatePlatform("100010", "Supplier 10");

    var mainsegment = ProductObjectMother.CreateMainSegment("123");
    var application = ProductObjectMother.CreateApplication("Foo");
    var productfamily = ProductObjectMother.CreateProductFamily("X99");

    Engine i = ProductObjectMother.CreateEngine(platform, productfamily, application, mainsegment);
    var repository = new ProductRepository();
    repository.Save(i);
    repository.Flush();
}
```

Comment: I suggest you to run the same code from a simple console application and check if you get the same error. I think `MSTest` is not the problem here. Also your code is not running using the `_transactionScope` and you don't rollback it anywhere.

Comment: Is your code running in single thread or business logic spawns some new threads?

Comment: What about adding `_transactionScope.Rollback()` before the `Dispose()` ?

Answer (score 2):

Problem seems to be with transaction that is neither committed using _transactionScope.Complete() or roll back by throwing exception.

Also I notice one strange thing, test usually fails or run successfully by "Assert" functions(equals, not equal, exists etc from assert) that is missing from your test. :)